# cURL contents from Proxy Servers

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Good day,

I have a script in PHP that gets contents from a URL. I used cURL for this. However, I wanted to get contents from proxy servers like http://www.canadaproxy.net/ and there seems to be no return values for the script.

Here are my PHP codes:

`$url = "http://www.canadaproxy.net/browse.php?u=Oi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jYS8%3D&b=5";`

`$timeout = 5;`

`$useragent = "Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)";`

`$ch = curl_init();`

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);`

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

`$raw = curl_exec($ch);`

`curl_close($ch);`

`var_dump($raw);`

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL should be: $url = "http://www.canadaproxy.net/includes/process.php?action=update";

Add

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "u=google.com");
```

and it will work